# How to remove the base url of your website from Google Analytics trackings?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, tracking, reveal.js

I've a question related to the simple tracking functionalities of Google Analytics.

I've realized my website with reveal.js, so my site follows a step navigation

```
http://[mywebsite.nl]/#/cover
http://[mywebsite.nl]/#/welkom
http://[mywebsite.nl]/#/pagina1
http://[mywebsite.nl]/#/pagina2
```

and I setup google analytics to track statistics.

My tracking issue is that when I land on my **http://[mywebsite.nl]** and I'm redirected to **http://[mywebsite.nl]/#/cover** it happens that the same page is tracked twice.
Is there a way to remove the tracking of the **/** of the website?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was easier than I thought, sometimes we tend to over complicate things..
This is the super easy answer I was looking for, it is necessary a small tune on the javascript code

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

if(window.location.pathname != '/'){
  ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXXX', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview');
}
```

It is just necessary to check the `window.location.pathname` and call the analytics function only for the desired urls.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Google's analytics.js tutorial, it allows some customization:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/pages

> Page - The page path and query string of the page (e.g. /homepage?id=10). This value must start with a / character.

GA is nice to use as is, it provides some valuable insights.
But it is generally more valuable to track not page views but user actions.
GA is about page views, but as soon as you really want to understand users behaviour you need to track actions. I would recommend to take a look at http://www.devmetrics.io or http://mixpanel.com analytics.

You specify event and its properties. That means that you have full control.

```
var pageName = document.location.pathname;
// custom pageName processing if you need
devmetrics.userEvent('page_load', [pageName]);
....
// inside button handler:
devmetrics.userEvent('button_click', [pageName]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend stripping the hostname from your pageviews, that can cause other issues with data quality.

Ideally, you would use a 3xx redirect to redirect from your main page to /#/cover, or don't send a hit before your site redirects. If that's not possible, you could try using a filter to drop hits from the URL you don't want to be double-counted.

You might try [Google Tag Assistant Recordings](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6277313?hl=en) to validate that your flow works as expected.